# Help me organize my rubies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

So I think I have a bunch of rubies scattered around here. I want to install rails 3 and watch the railscast online and the person uses rvm to manage ruby versions. I went to install rvm and followed the instruction. I got to the point where I need to do

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

EDIT: and I did

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

However after the installation, I try

```
ruby -v
```

and get

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

I also go and do

```
which ruby
```

and get

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

How do I set up my path so that I can use the ruby that is installed using rvm?

inside /Users/denniss/.rvm/bin I have the ruby-1.9.2-rc2

and my .profile looks like

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/android/tools"
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/rubystack/apache2/bin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/denniss/.rvm/bin/:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I forgot to add the

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

at the very end of my ~/.profile

Answer (score 2):

Type:

```
rvm list
```

That'll display all the versions of ruby you have.

Then type :

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

And everytime you open you're terminal it will default to your original ruby. To change this type :

```
rvm --default 1.9.2
```

Note: You don't need to use RVM to use Rails3. I recommend keeping the ruby v you have, and just installed rails 3 for the new app. Rails 2 and Rails 3 will not overwrite each other.

Comment: I did that and I saw that ruby 1.9.2 is the only one listed. I have edited my post and I already did rvm 1.9.2 and still the ruby -v returns me the one located in 
/usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Try copying and pasting exactly what ruby version it is for example "ruby-1.9.2-head" or "ruby-1.9.1-p378" and make the full bash statement say `$> rvm use ruby-1.9.1-p378" or whatever your actual version is.

Comment: And you have to type the word `use` ! don't forget that part or it won't work. So it has to be `rvm use 1.9.2` :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to the new version with `rvm 1.9.2`.  This is only temporary, however.  To permanently set it, you can pass the --default: `rvm --default 1.9.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, if RVM is not loading the used ruby into the environment then you are most likely not sourcing it in your profiles.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

This is in both the installer output and the documentation for installation:

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

~Wayne